# COUNTIF and IMPORTRANGE returning 0 when referencing another cell

Tags: google-sheets-formula, countif

I have a similar issue. However, I am trying to countif in reference to another cell:

```
=Countif(Importrange("Sheet name", "'Sheet Tab"!DE:FH), "="&A3)
```

but get 0 for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Closing quotes are missing

```
"'Sheet Tab'"!DE:FH"
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("Sheet_ID", "Sheet Tab!DE:FH"), A3)
```